# Get-ADUser - finding a user using both GivenName (FirstName) and Surname

Tags: powershell

Really simple..

Looking to create a powershell script that returns an AD result if a user is found.

I'm using FirstName and Surname as variables. My script so far looks a little something like this...

```
$FirstName = Read-Host "Please enter the First Name of the new user"

$Surname = Read-Host "Please enter the Surname of the new user"

Get-ADUser -f "GivenName -eq '$FirstName'" -and "Surname -eq '$Surname'"
```

When I run each part of the Get-ADUser command (so search by first name, search by surname) it returns the expected result.

When I add -and as an operator, so both conditions are satisfied, I get this:

```
Get-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'and'.
At line:4 char:44
+ Get-ADUser -f "GivenName -eq '$FirstName'" -and "Surname -eq '$Surnam ...
+                                            ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management. 
   Commands.GetADUser
```

Where in the hell am I going wrong!?

Comment: I commend to your attention the details of the filter language as described in [Microsoft Docs on `Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps).

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and worked,

```
$FirstName = Read-host 'enter first name'
$LastName = Read-Host 'enter last name'

Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$FirstName' -and SurName -eq 
'$LastName'"
```

check for the quotes on your code

Answer (score 0):

This works with ambiguous name resolution as well.

```
Get-ADUser -filter "anr -eq '$FirstName $Surname'"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is our wildcard lookup script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ea Inquire -NoClobber
```

$user = read-host -prompt "What partial username?"
(Get-ADUser -Properties Name,GivenName,SurName,UserPrincipalName,Enabled,Lockedout -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase "DC=NA,DC=BVCORP,DC=Net" -Filter ("UserPrincipalName -like '*$user*'") -EA silentlycontinue|where ObjectClass -eq 'user'|select -ExcludeProperty SID,DistinguishedName -Property Name,GivenName,SurName,UserPrincipalName,Enabled,Lockedout)